# Why fountains change their colors?

Tags: wazhack

Sometimes fountains turn `blue` or `pink` when you drink from them. Is there any significance to this?

Answer (score 2):

Per [the wiki](http://wazhack.wikia.com/wiki/Fountain):

> **Drinking Effects**
>
> - Restoring mana, as per quaffing an uncursed Potion of Mana (the water turns blue)
> - Restoring HP, as per quaffing an uncursed Potion of Healing (the water turns red)